# How to disable Emacs electric braces inside HERE docs

Tags: emacs

In Emacs, is there a way to automatically disable electric braces when within a HERE doc region? When I'm trying to type sentences within a HERE doc, Emacs keeps inserting branches and newline when I type language keywords such as for and if. I have a key to turn them off, but I wondered if there was an automatic way.

Answer (score 0):

You need a parser to detect if inside a here-document.
Then advice the function which inserts braces to stop if true.

WRT to the first part, a generic parser is available here:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~a-roehler/s-x-emacs-werkstatt/trunk/view/head:/beg-end.el

To view some example of usage maybe have a look into

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~a-roehler/s-x-emacs-werkstatt/trunk/view/head:/sh-werkstatt.el